# Dash through enemies and dont taking damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my Player character dash through specific enemies and don't take any damage during de dash animation, here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using CnControls;

public class PlayerDash : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator myAnim;
private bool dash = false;
private float dashTimer = 0;
private float dashCd = 0.3f;
public Collider2D[] Coll;

void Start () {
    myAnim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
void Update () {
    if (CnInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Dash") && !dash) {
        dash = true;
        dashTimer = dashCd;
        myAnim.SetBool ("Dash", dash);
        foreach (Collider2D coll in Coll) {
            if (coll.gameObject.tag == ("Enemy")) {
                coll.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dash) {
        if (dashTimer > 0) {
            dashTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        } else {
            dash = false;
            myAnim.SetBool ("Dash", false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Everything is working fine, but when i use dash and collide with a "dasheable" enemy, every "dasheable" enemy  don't inflict damage to the Player(that's because the condition i use), what conditions should i use to make enemy colliders still being active after i dash the first one, already tryed some options here and nothing seems to work properly

Comment: In your update you disabled the collider. Enabled Behaviours are Updated, disabled Behaviours are not - thus says the manual. I am making an assumption, as your "enemy inflicting damage" code is not posted.

Comment: Figured out, i created a method outside Update to check if the Player are using dash and then i called it back in Update, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a bool `invincible` (or if you want to get more fancy, a simple state machine). Your script that deals with damage to the player can then check whether for not the player is currently invincible, then it ignores the damage.

That way for your dash, or any other animation where you'd want the player to not take damage, just turn on invincible at the start, and then turn it off at the end.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Figured out, i created a method outside Update to check if player are dashin and then called it back in Update, thanks.

```
void enterDashing() {
    foreach (Collider2D coll in Coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && !dash) {
            coll.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding this and doing something similar to my solution posted above. the solution you posted here will only ever work for your dash animation. What if in the future, you want another animation that makes them invincible? What if you want to make a powerup that makes them invincible? my posted solution is MUCH more future proof since it allows you to set the player invincible and not invincible at will and will avoid conflicts with different things that affect invincibility.